# Task based vs. thread based Watchdog - but async needed

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

We're using watchdogs to determine whether a connected system is still alive or not.

In the previous code we used TCP directly and treated the watchdog in a separate thread. Now is a new service used that provides it's data using gRPC.

For that we tried using the async interface with tasks but a task based watchdog will fail.

I wrote a small [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fz6woE) that abstracts the code and illustrates the problem. You can switch between task based watchdog and thread based watchdog by commenting out line 18 with `//`.

The demo contains this code that causes the problem:

```
async Task gRPCSendAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => await Task.Yield();
async Task gRPCReceiveAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) => await Task.Yield();

var  start = DateTime.UtcNow;
await gRPCSendAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
await gRPCReceiveAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
var end = DateTime.UtcNow;

if ((end - start).TotalMilliseconds >= 100)
    // signal failing
```

If this code is used in `Task.Run` it will signal failing if the application has a lot cpu-work to do in other tasks.

If a dedicated thread is used the watchdog works as expected and no problem is raise.

I do understand the problem: All code after await may be (if not finished already or does not contain a "real" await) queued to the thread pool. But the thread pool has other things to do so that it took too long to finish the method.

Yes the simple answer is: USE THREAD.

But using a thread limits us to only use synchronous methods. There is no way to call an async method out of a thread. I created another [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0upUw2) that shows that all code after first `await` will be queued to thread bool so that `CallAsync().Wait()` will not work. (Btw. that issue is much more handled [here](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/).)

We're having a lot of async code that may be used within such time critical operations.

So the question is: Is there any way to perform that that operations using tasks with async/await?

Maybe I'm completely wrong and creating an task based watchdog should be done very differently.

*thoughts*

I was thinking about `System.Threading.Timer` but the problem of async sending and async receiving will cause that problem anyways.

Comment: Have you considered [increasing the minimum number of threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) the thread pool creates on demand, by calling for example `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 10);` at the start of the program?

Comment: As a side note, comparing `DateTime`s obtained by calls to `UtcNow` is not a reliable way to measure durations, because it depends on the system clock that can be subject to non-deterministic adjustments. I would suggest to use a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes I did - but that's not a real solution. That only shifts the problem a little to the future. Besides not every used CPU provides 64 threads so this would be a tightrope walk between thread switching costs and number of threads.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes I know. Our productive code is using Stopwatch but that does not matter and I tried to create a simple demo that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Would you consider a solution that is based on a third-party library, and specifically on Stephen Cleary's [Nito.AsyncEx.Context](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Context)? This library can help in keeping async-await confined in a dedicated thread.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias We're currently using `Nito.AsyncEx` for other reasons and there is no reason against `Context`. I did't tried it before because I didn't know about it. I'll give it a try - after reading a little documentation to understand what it does. Thx for that hint.

Comment: You should probably use [gRPC keepalives](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md). Though to be blunt, if you have thread pool exhaustion, then pretty much everything asynchronous has the possibility of significant delays.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thx for the keepalives-hint. Nevertheless it feels like general problem. What if we have an application that has a lot of workload and should also handle asynchronous operations like reading network streams. I understand the reasons that cause the problem. Still, we want to use asynchronous operations, which is difficult to do with dedicated threads. Increasing the number of threads in the thread pool cannot be the general solution, especially since I'm not even sure if this solves the problem at all. What is the general solution for asynchronous code in dedicated threads?

Comment: @SebastianSchumann: I believe the general solution is to increase the thread pool size and *limit* the amount of workload. If you need a dedicated thread for a specific asynchronous operation, `AsyncContext` is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could use Stephen Cleary's [`AsyncContext`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/5.0.0/netstandard2.0/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext) class from the [Nito.AsyncEx.Context](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Context) package, in order to constrain an asynchronous workflow to a dedicated thread:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
    {
        await DoTheWatchdogAsync(watchdogCts.Token);
    });
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

The call to `AsyncContext.Run` will block until the supplied asynchronous operation is completed. All asynchronous continuations created by the `DoTheWatchdogAsync` will be processed internally by the `AsyncContext` on the current thread. In the above example the current thread is not a `ThreadPool` thread, because of the flag [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) used in the construction of the wrapper `Task`. You could confirm this by querying the property [`Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isthreadpoolthread).

If you prefer you could use a traditional `Thread` constructor instead of the somewhat unconventional `Task.Factory.StartNew`+`LongRunning`.

Comment: Mostly. This is the best hope I've seen so far. [I tried it.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F9hXfk) But the problem is that I have to remove `.ConfigureAwait(false);` to make it work. If line 43 and 44 are invoked using `.ConfigureAwait(false);` it doesn't work. At the moment I didn't understand why this isn't working.To be continued...

Comment: @SebastianSchumann yeap, good point. Any `ConfigureAwait(false)` will send the continuation to the `ThreadPool`, so you should remove all of them in order to stay in the `AsyncContext`.

Comment: Due to the explanations from @StephenCleary I accepted this answer because using `AsyncContext` is the best option we have. Thx.

Comment: I should note that the `AsyncContext` solution is only effective at the top level. If for example the methods `gRPCSendAsync` and `gRPCReceiveAsync` depend on `ThreadPool` threads for their internal workings, then probably you'll not get any benefit from using the `AsyncContext`.